# each() function does not affect all Users

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I want set a field for each user by using this Cloud Code

```
    queryForUsers.each(function(item){
        item.set("rank",1);
        item.save();
    },{
        success: function() {response.success();}
    },
    {
        error: function(error) {response.error(error);}
    });
```

But it's does not affect all users. It affects around of 130-150 users and that's all.
Here is a log

[image]

Is there a way to solve that problem?

Comment: there's a longer answer, but start by returning the save promise... instead of item.save(), try `return item.save();`

Comment: I got a lot of "Request timed out"

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting a 124 error, which means that you are making too many requests in a short period of time. I would add a [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) method to your loop to space out the requests.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, you can saveAll the items which will only take one API request.

```
var itemArray = [];
queryForUsers.each(function(item){
    item.set("rank",1);
    itemArray.push(item);
},{
    success: function() {
        Parse.Object.saveAll(itemArray, {
            success: function() {response.success();}
        },
            error: function(error) {response.error(error);}
        }            
    }
},
{
    error: function(error) {response.error(error);}
});
```

Comment: What code should I place in setTimeout()? (I call Cloud Code only one time on client side)

Comment: @user2686299 I edited my response with an additional solution. Let me know if it is useful.

Comment: it just says the there is some error in saveAll function